# Duplicating Request Headers from Android Packets to Connect to a WebSocket Server

Tags: android, node.js, websocket

I am trying to connect to a WebSocket server that my Android device connects to from an app. I captured the packets on my Android device, and the initial request headers look like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: example.com:80
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ysWaBflPV9EmRaB1JpPMOQ==
Origin: http://example.com:80
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: default-protocol
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: 
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

The response from the server looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2018 02:37:20 GMT
Connection: upgrade
Set-Cookie:     AWSALB=0yaRd5HOPlZSITp+bcXoZoIn/7YOOqE9o4/t/8b3kw2PTxooflm/85w+1JfudEE0Cwb1BUkWPV+t4kOnEm4FbLSWwMMFp8URbblZKj0a0kd0xB+glbLBHWxc/TPW; Expires=Wed, 07 Feb 2018     02:37:20 GMT; Path=/
Server: nginx/1.12.1
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: bj5wLF8vmyDrA7pqEgbHKbxqQSU=
```

Then, some communication begins, with lots of unrecognizable characters and some clear words in the messages. I don't have much experience with WebSockets, but I assume it is some form of compression.

I was able to send an identical request to this server using the ws module in Node.js, and I got an identical response to the one above. One notable difference was that when I set the protocol header to default-protocol, I received an error saying "Server sent no subprotocol". Without using this header, I still got the same response.

After the initial response, however, I did not receive any more messages, even though I did on my Android device. After about 30 seconds, the connection closes with code 1006 and no further information.

I tested the same request with curl and received the same headers back, but it also closed after about 30 seconds saying:
"Empty reply from server"

So my main question is obviously: What is going wrong, and how can I fix it?

More specifically, I am wondering if anyone with WebSocket experience knows if it is a problem with my client, or with the server itself.

It is possible that the server is authenticating me in some way on my Android device, but the headers that I captured are not revealing anything about that. Is it ever customary to authenticate a connection with a later message in the client-server communications? Is it possible that a separate HTTP request is authenticating me for this WebSocket server? All of these things seem unlikely to me since I found no other packets with anything related to auth requests. It seems much more likely that there is something wrong with the messages being sent.

Comment: There's a whole webSocket handshake, including some security stuff and then a webSocket frame data format.  You have to implement all that in order to make a webSocket connection.  You can read about it [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers).

Comment: Thanks. Upon analyzing the packets closer, I realized that there is definitely some authentication going on, as there is data specific to me that is sent. Am I right in saying that there is definitely no auth going on in those first two headers that I showed? I notice that I immediately get kicked out of the server if I send a random message. Do you think this indicates that the server is awaiting another message which authenticates me?

Comment: I don't see any authentication stuff in what you show in your question.  Since a webSocket connection starts with an http request, many forms of HTTP authentication can be used at the start of a webSocket connection.  When you start sending data are you using the whole webSocket data format with the appropriate security key?

Comment: Yes, I included all headers, unless something is somehow eluding the packet capture. Is it ever customary to have the client send an auth message as the very first message after the initial handshake, once the connection has been upgraded?

Comment: Yes, that can be done.  It requires some state management on the server side of the webSocket to not allow any data exchange except the auth step until it has been complated, but that can certainly be done.